# Real life example of high cohesion and loose coupling for presentation

Tags: design-patterns, loose-coupling, cohesion, audience

I need to do a presentation about high cohesion and loose coupling. To explain this to my audience, I need to come up with a real life example (not code-based) of those 2 terms and I kinda have difficulties to find one. Therefore I would like to ask if you have any good ideas?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: This question is primarily opinion based; additionally it does not show any research effort.

Answer (score 1):

A modern auto plant can be used to illustrate the concepts of coupling and cohesion. Each worker within the plant has one specific job, like mounting a cylinder head on an engine. This is an example of cohesion. The worker does one thing and does it the same way every time. The worker doesn't have any idea about the vehicle in which the engine will be installed.

The engine, when completed, might be used in a 2 door coupe or it may go in a small truck. The engine doesn't care which vehicle it's installed in and the vehicle doesn't care which engine is used. The connections between the engine and the vehicle are designed to as be generic as possible and the engine specific connection points are minimized. This is an example of low coupling.